# How to create custom toolbar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create AppBar like this in the Flutter.

[image]

But I have no idea how to create AppBar given in image.
Also I want to hide or show each button in `AppBar` individually whenever I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In there you can add decoration with a rounded corner to get the round corner in the bottom of the AppBar. Use the Row widget to add child components like text and the icons inside the AppBar

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size(double.infinity, 100),
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.black12,
          spreadRadius: 5,
          blurRadius: 2
        )]
      ),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 100,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),bottomRight: Radius.circular(20))
        ),
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.navigate_before,size: 40,color: Colors.white,),
              Text("Foodbar",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30,color: Colors.white),),
              Icon(Icons.navigate_before,color: Colors.transparent,),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),

  body: Center(
  ),
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(48.0),
              child: Container(
                 color: Colors.white,                
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: //body
      ),
    );
  }
}
```